# C# Visio Addon - Iterate through current selection

Tags: c#, visio

I have the following code:

```
        var currentSelection = activeWindow.Selection;

        if (currentSelection != null)
        {
            int numberOfShapes = currentSelection.Count;

            for( int i = 1; i <= numberOfShapes; i++)
            {

                currentSelection.Select(? ,Visio.VisSelectArgs.visSelect);
            }  
        }
```

As you can see I am iterating through a shape selection in Visio. I am struggle with the SheetObject parameter in the Select Method. I want to implement this dynamically so I iterate through all shapes (regardless of name) - what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through the current selection is as simple as a `For Each` on the `Selection` collection, e.g.:

```
Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection
    MsgBox shp.Name
Next
```